# Why when I query information in a table the updateDateColumn gets updated?

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am making a get request to my API and I want to use the table's changeDate field to run some logic, but the problem is that when I request the data this field gets updated and that's not the behavior I expected from the @UpdateDateColumn decorator since I'm just doing a simple get query with the Repository API. Why does this happens? Did I miss something in the docs?
I know this because I gave read only permissions (mysql) to my API, when I make a request it failed because of this.

This is the error:
`QueryFailedError: The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement`

This is my entity (part of it):

```js
export class Cake{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Index()
  @Column()
  @Generated('uuid')
  GUID: string;
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  flavor: string;
  @UpdateDateColumn({ nullable: true })
  changeDate: Date;
}
```

This is my query:

```js
const cake= await this.cakeRepository.findOne({where: {GUID: guid}, select: ['id', 'GUID', 'changeDate']})
```

SQL for table creation

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Cake` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GUID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`changeDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
`flavor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_6aeaf4ee4a4e43e805a15c4738` (`GUID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=362 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: edit your question to show your table schema (output of `show create table yourtablename` in the mysql command line client, as text not an image)

Comment: @ysth added table create